# Не работает вычисление в скрипте

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

В скрипте производятся вычисления, но при нажатии на кнопку "Вычислить" ничего не происходит, я не понял в чём дело или где ошибка?

```
function areaRectangle7(){
var D2=document.forma1.t22.value||0;
  var D3=document.forma1.t23.value||0;
  var h2=document.forma1.t24.value||0;
  var m=document.forma1.t25.value||0;
  var pi=Math.PI; //это число пи

  if ( (D2 == 0) || (D3 == 0) || (h2 == 0) (m == 0) ) {
        alert('Входные данные не могут быть равны 0');
      return;
    }
    if ( (D2 < 0) || (D3 < 0) || (h2 < 0) (m == 0) ) {
        alert('Входные данные не могут быть меньше 0');
      return;
    }   
  var V2=(pi/4)*(D2-D3)*(h2*m);
  document.forma1.res7.value=V2.toFixed(2);
  }
```

И конечно же форма

```
<table align="center">
<p align="center">Объем закрепляемой зоны</p>
<tr><td height="40px">
<div class="price">Диаметр закрепляемой зоны, м;</div><input name="t22" id="t22" type="text" align="right" size="4" maxlength="8"  onkeyup="return proverka(this)">
</td></tr>
<tr><td height="40px">
<div class="price">Наружный диаметр эксплуатационной колонны, м;</div><input name="t23" id="t23" type="text" align="right" size="4" maxlength="8"  onkeyup="return proverka(this)">
</td></tr>
<tr><td height="40px">
<div class="price">Эффективная мощность пласта, м;</div><input name="t24" id="t24" type="text" align="right" size="4"  maxlength="8"  onkeyup="return proverka(this)">
</td></tr>
<tr><td height="40px">
<div class="price">Условная пористость закрепляемой зоны;</div><input name="t25" id="t25" type="text" align="right" size="4"  maxlength="8"  onkeyup="return proverka(this)">
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<input type="button" name="button" value="Вычислить" onClick="areaRectangle7();">
<input type="text" name="res7" size="10">
</td></tr>
</table>
```

Рабочий скрипт

```
    function areaRectangle6(){
var D1=document.forma1.t20.value||0;
  var h1=document.forma1.t21.value||0;
  var pi=Math.PI; //это число пи
  if ( (D1 == 0) || (h1 == 0) ) {
        alert('Входные данные не могут быть равны 0');
      return;
    }
    if ( (D1 < 0) || (h1 < 0) ) {
        alert('Входные данные не могут быть меньше 0');
      return;
    }   
  var V1=(pi/4)*Math.pow(D1, 2)*h1; //D1 во 2 степени
  document.forma1.res6.value=V1.toFixed(2);
  }
```

**UPD**

Покажу яснее на картинке. Не работает скрипт, в выделенной красным цветом рамке
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нажмите в браузер F12 (Developer Tools), найдите закладку "Console" и посмотрите, нет ли там сообщений об ошибках.

Comment: у меня недоступна консоль, я в браузере Яндекс сижу

Comment: и никакого другого браузера у Вас на компьютере нет?

Comment: к сожалению другие браузеры не поддерживаются или просто тормозят,компьютер не такой уж новый,ему пару лет

Comment: кто-то что-то не договаривает... моему 7 лет, на нём все браузеры работают ;) тяжело вам будет без консоли...

Comment: Использовать как средство разработки браузер без консоли - "Лучше, конечно, помучиться" Товарищ Сухов.

Comment: я на денвере пишу

Comment: При чем здесь Денвер (город в Колорадо)?

Comment: возможно я немного и невнимателен, но в чём же всё таки ошибка моего прблемного скрипта?

Comment: я выложил работающий скрипт, сравните с неработающим

Comment: Никто не знает в чём ошибка? Я тем более незнаю

Comment: чего все молчат?

Comment: Так в Яндекс браузере есть консоль...

Answer (score 3):

Пропущен знак || между последними двумя проверками в этих if-ах

```
if ( (D2 == 0) || (D3 == 0) || (h2 == 0) (m == 0) )
if ( (D2 < 0) || (D3 < 0) || (h2 < 0) (m == 0) )
```

Comment: Спасибо, я разобрался